# How to download multiple build artifacts in a Release pipeline on Azure Devops?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am trying to create a Releasing stage that is meant to download 3 different build artifacts from 3 different pipelines in a project and deploy them on a target machine. When I create a release and deploy it on the target machine, the very first download build artifact task works fine but none of the following ones and I see the following error

***"Artifact [buildnumber] not found for build [buildId]. Please ensure you have published artifacts in any previous phases of the current build."***

Has anyone else seen this error or know why I am getting this error?

[image: Screenshot of error message]

Thank

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use [Download Build Artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops) task to download different build artifacts from different pipelines, please select the “**Specific build**” option to find that particular artifact, as below.
[image]

If you use the default value: **Current build**, of course this task cannot find other build artifacts from other build pipelines. And then you will encounter this issue.

In addition, the new release will automatically download artifacts in below pre-defined “**Download Artifacts**” step.
[image]
Therefore, you could just add these 3 artifacts in release pipeline, and then you don’t need to use additional [Download Build Artifacts task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops) to download these artifacts. See: [Release artifacts and artifact sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/artifacts?view=azure-devops) for details.
[image]

Comment: As mentioned above I added alln3 artifacts under a single release pipeline. And created 3 stages one after another to deploy 1 artifact at a time. Now during deployment, one of the stages is skipping the "Downloading Artifacts" task.

Comment: It only does "Initialise job" and "Finalize job". The build artifact is published in the build pipeline. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: By default, packages are downloaded to the agent. Please check if you enable the "Skip download of artifacts" option under the Agent job in this stage to skip the download of artifacts. See: [Artifact sources - Azure Artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/artifacts?view=azure-devops#artifact-sources---azure-artifacts) for details.

Comment: As suggested, I checked the setting and it was enabled for all build artifacts. Out of 3 artifacts, it downloads 2 but skips 1.   Could it be because I am selecting specific builds while creating a release and that build(which is skipping) was released prior in another release?

Comment: I wanted to add a screenshot but this comment box doesn't allow me to add one.

Comment: You could add these 3 artifacts as the source of release pipeline artifact, and then they will be downloaded automatically, and you could find them in the artifact directory. If your issue persists, as the comment in the forum has more limitation to discuss your current issue(cannot attach screenshots, etc.), could you please file a new ticket with latest situation(pipeline definition, release logs, screenshots) to describe your current issue, so we can go on further investigation? Thanks for your cooperation.